# Samsung watch web app vibration intensity

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I chose the web app in Tizen studio and tried to make a vibration using `Navigator.vibrate()`.

https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/vibration-api-tizen-web-app

But it seems that there is no way to set the vibration intensity.

Do you have any clue on it.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no support for various intensity of vibration in web application on Tizen.

You can check [Feedback Web Device API](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/6.0/device_api/mobile/tizen/feedback.html) which allows predefined styles of vibrations. They have differences in length and/or number of vibration events, but not in the intensity. Still maybe you will find some acceptable pattern/style.